# jquery to mvc methode

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I would like to delete a db-entry using jQuery and a mvc-actionmethode. But I can't seem to get the deletemethode working..

[Index.cshtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cN8OW.png)

**code controller**

```
    // DELETE: api/Categories/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Category))]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteCategory(int id)
    {
        Category category = db.Categories.Find(id);
        if (category == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.Categories.Remove(category);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(category);
    }
```

Comment: You need to declare and initialise your database connection

Comment: please post relevant code. not images

Comment: So which part is not working ?

Comment: Also, the server side is not relevant here providing your client side call is reaching the server. Where do you declare your entities? The above code should not compile.

Comment: Your method names should match the http verb you are calling, assuming this is an api controller.  So you need to change DeleteCategory to Delete.

Comment: alert(item) will never call your api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's get started. I'm assuming that you are using an `ApiController`.

If you use a controller called Categories, then it's a good practice to use the name of your method the verb it represents. If you want to send a `DELETE: api/categories/id`, then you should have your method:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Category))]
public IHttpActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    Category category = db.Categories.Find(id);
    if (category == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    db.Categories.Remove(category);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return Ok(category);
}
```

If you really want to call it DeleteCategory, then you should say what `http verb` it represents:

```
[HttpDelete]
[ResponseType(typeof(Category))]
public IHttpActionResult DeleteCategory(int id)
{
    Category category = db.Categories.Find(id);
    if (category == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    db.Categories.Remove(category);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return Ok(category);
}
```

But the main reason it's not working is because your `function` is not doing anything but calling an `alert`

```
function DeleteCategory(item) 
{
    alert(item);
}
```

ps: Don't use curly braces on the next line while you are working with javascript. You can fall into problems with javascript's automatic semicolon insertion. Always do:

```
function DeleteCategory(item) {
    alert(item);
}
```

Comment: Hi Rafael 
Thx  for the headsup on the HttpDelete

Answer (score 0):

I'm really thankful for all of your remarks. I'm pretty new to stackflow and programming, as you can see!

I tried alert just to make sure my function is working, incl item.

The difficult part is how can I call my delete-method and for this delete the specific item...